# VS Code Debug with chrome spitting out weird error after no change: Unable to launch browser: "(void 0) is not a constructor"

Tags: visual-studio-code

When trying to launch a debug session through the debug tab, I get this error.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/TF5A6.png)

> Unable to launch browser: "(void 0) is not a constructor"

Rolled back changes to my launch.json to before this started and that wasn't the problem. Can't find any answers on here or google. This is running in a remote instance.

Comment: Same issue.  vscode just got an update, maybe they broke something?  Using firefox instead of chrome works.

Answer (score 2):

This issue seems to be tracked here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/178786

Comment: This is now fixed for me after updating to version 1.77.1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).